# I can not keep within 1 second

Tags: python, csv, openpyxl, xlsx

**Instead of 1000 ms, my code fits in 1014
Please help me with the optimization**

Condition:

*In the Excel office program (or its analogues), you can always save the table in csv format.*
*Imagine that this functionality is broken.
Write your own excel -> csv transcoder using the appropriate libraries.
Your program should open the data.xlsx file containing arbitrary data and save the result in output.csv*

*Input format:
Not*

*Output format:
In the output.csv file, output data from the source file in csv format.
Separator - "semicolon"
Quotation - quotation marks*

*Notes:
Use the csv module*

***My code***

```
import csv
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='data.xlsx', data_only=True)
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
    ws = wb.active
    rows = []
    for row in ws.values:
        w = map(lambda x: float(x) if x is not None and type(x) != str else x, row)   
        rows.append(w)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

you need to optimize the code, but so that all the functionality remains

Sample tests:

[image]

Note:
These lines of code are responsible for preserving the decimal places of float numbers, converted to integers for recording in a file

```
w = map(lambda x: float(x) if x is not None and type(x) != str else x, row)
```

*they cannot be omitted*

***link to test xlsx file***:
https://yadi.sk/i/bF-5kOMTuyuMMg

Comment: some suggested using Pandas, but that’s not what I need

Comment: Paste the text of the input and output, not an image, so it can be used for testing.  Nobody wants to type in manually, esp. in Cyrillic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The float conversion can be slightly faster with:

```
w = map(lambda x: float(x) if type(x) is int else x, row)
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but it is still 35 ms slower than necessary.

Comment: @НикитаРазуваев There's not much left to change.  You could try `xlrd` library instead of `openpxl`.